# How to provide web access to interact with a file system?

Tags: webserver, file-sharing, sshfs

I need to be able to provide web access to interact with a file system, to upload and download files to a directory. In general people will access these files using sshfs but in a pinch we want people to have web access to these files. We want to run a web server, probably apache2, and some kind of web app or something on the file server which will allow people to log into the website and interact with the file system. If this web access was anything like dropbox that'd be great but it doesn't have to be nearly that slick. We just need upload and download capabilities.

We don't want to use WebDAV or SparkleShare.

Does anyone have any good recommendations for open source tools to do this or even some good web search keywords I could use to find it myself? So far I haven't found what I'm looking for because I don't really know what to look for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out a web-based file manager like Mollify.
I'm sure there's others out there too.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/mollify